# How should I place "Indeed" in sentence

Tags: word-usage, adverb-position

I would like to say sorry first for my bad english, and I hope you understand me .

I have been improving my english recently and I thought about adding "indeed" into my essays , I have certainly understood the meaning but I couldn't find any information about placing "indeed" in a sentence .

I found out that when you are using "very" in your sentence you have to use "indeed" at the end of your sentence . How can I use "indeed" in sentences without "very" ?

Comment: You don't have to use it at the end of a sentence, and you can use it to strengthen or confirm an  adjective, or noun: "His face was indeed, green."  "It was, indeed, Harry at the door."

Comment: Indeed, the use of very is not obligatory.

Comment: "Indeed" is one of those words that you need understand pretty well to use without sounding awkward.  While "very" and "indeed" are often used in the same sentence, they are not joined at the hip.

Comment: What Hot Licks said. Forget indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You might use "indeed" without "very" very well indeed. But you might have omitted "very" without changing the meaning of the sentence much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google ngram to search for 'indeed' you will see that its use is declining slowly.

[Google ngram: indeed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indeed&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindeed%3B%2Cc0)

If you click on links at the bottom of that page you can read the texts and see how the word is used in real life.

Comment: what does it mean "declining slowly" , does it mean that I should not use it ?

Comment: @user3730848 No, just that it is becoming less common to use it than it was before. You can still use it.

Comment: You will likely notice that about half the uses of "indeed" are plays on the old adage "A friend in need is a friend indeed".